# How can i manage CORS error in angular 10? i alredy use proxy but i need the solution for production

Tags: angular, api, cors

im trying to solve the CORS problem for an api in production, i alredy tried the proxy.conf.json but doesnt work well for production, just in development. I dont know how to make this work properly, if anybody have an example it would be great. Here is my proxy.conf.json:

```
{
"/validation/v1/reference/*": {
    "target":"https://secure.epayco.co",
    "secure":false,
    "changeOrigin":true
},
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't solve cors issue in UI side. You need to fix this cors issue in server side. If your service is in nodejs/python/java/.net. You can set Access-Control-Allow-Origin in api side. But if the service and UI both deployed in same web server under same domain in production. In that case you don't need to do anything as the root domain of the UI and API is same.